# Toshiba Libretto 100CT PS/2 keyboard and mouse dual use

Tags: keyboards, mouse, laptop

I have a [Toshiba Libretto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toshiba_Libretto) 100CT that I'd like to use in docked configuration with an external monitor, speakers, keyboard and mouse

Through the use of the official dock I'm able to use a VGA port for video and the 2.5mm audio output.

According to the manual it has a [PS/2 keyboard/mouse port](https://www.minuszerodegrees.net/manuals/Toshiba/Libretto/Toshiba%20Libretto%20100CT%20-%20Product%20Specifications.pdf). So using this port directly I can either connect a keyboard or mouse, but not both.

My question is **whether it's possible to use a [PS/2 splitter cable](https://cpc.farnell.com/unbranded/ex-099/splitter-cable-ps2-0-25m/dp/CS07840)** so that I can connect both a keyboard and mouse at the same time?

Comment: A serial mouse is always an option if you can't get this to work. A serial port card in the PCMCIA slot if the dock is unavailable could work too. Even USB in the PCMCIA slot is an option if you have OS support.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

##### TL;DR

Yes, *assuming* that the Libretto has ***both*** the mouse and keyboard inputs wired up to the dual purpose PS/2 port in the docking station, as can be inferred from the specifications/manual, then a splitter cable should work as expected.

---

The PS/2 connector has 6 pins:

1. Data
2. Not used
3. GND
4. +5V
5. Clock
6. Not used

[image: PS/2 connector pin out]

Image taken from [So how does a PS/2 keyboard interface work?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aXbh9VUB3U) at [00:30](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7aXbh9VUB3U&t=30).

Note: Both PS/2 keyboards and mice use the same two pins (1 and 5) to communicate.

However, the circuits that those two pins are connected to, *within in the computer*, differ, depending on *which device* the port has been physically assigned to:

- The mouse port - pins 1 and 5 are connected *only* to the mouse handling circuitry;
- The keyboard port - pins 1 and 5 are connected *only* to the keyboard handling circuitry.

That is why, if you plug a keyboard into a mouse port, the keyboard doesn't work, because the circuitry just isn't present at that port.

As an aside, keyboards send two data packets and mice send three.

However, a **dual purpose PS/2 port** has the pins assigned differently, and the keyboard and mouse handling circuits are both connected to the port, at the same time, albeit using different pins:

1. Keyboard data
2. Mouse data
3. GND
4. +5V
5. Keyboard clock
6. Mouse clock

[image: Photo of dual purpose PS/2 port]

From the pinout, you can see that the mouse (pins 2 and 6) uses a different pair of pins to the keyboard (pins 1 and 5). Therefore, a splitter cable can be used to effectively "separate" the wire pairs, for the respective devices, to two separate PS/2 connectors.

The splitter then routes:

- pins 1 and 5 to pins 1 and 5 of one of the resultant PS/2 connectors, and;
- pins 2 and 6 to pins 1 and 5 of the other resultant PS/2 connector.

Some brands colour code the resulting connectors appropriately (such as the Lindy, StartTech and Delock branded Y splitters):

[image: Colour coded Y splitter]

---

Also, please read the notes under the following diagram from [Wikipedia page for the PS/2 port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PS/2_port):

[image: Diagram of PS/2 connector from Wikipedia]

Note *a*:

> Keyboard and mouse ports may be combined into a single port which can be used to connect both by splitter cable.

and notes *b* and *c*:

> Sometimes, mouse Data/Clock for splitter cable.

Comment: Might want to expand on why it's only *probably* and *theoretically*, as currently this can only be guessed from how the pinout diagrams actually label pins 2 and 6, contrary to your description. (Also, I don't think it's correct to say either pair of clock and data pins is dedicated specifically to the mouse or keyboard: I haven't noticed a passive splitter ever bother to label its socket sides, implying they are entirely symmetrical)

Comment: The splitters produced by Lindy, StarTec and Delock brands (amongst others) colour code the resultant PS/2 connectors. However, whether they are actually symmetrical or not would need to be checked with a meter or continuity checker.

Comment: A continuity checker wouldn’t reveal much, it’s a matter of whether the target PS/2 port can handle it. If a single PS/2 port can handle either a mouse or a keyboard when connected on its own, then it should presumably be able to handle either device when connected to either pair of clock/data pins, and it doesn’t matter which is connected to which.

Comment: This is a good generic answer about splitting dual purpose PS/2 ports. Rather than give it a negative vote, someone could edit the answer to add specific information for Toshiba products. But is the problem that if the answer is then up voted, they person who edits doesn't get a reputation boost?

Comment: @AlexCannon - I agree that some data specific to the Libretto Dock would be useful. However, there is no reason to suspect that the Libretto does not provide a standard generic "dual purpose" PS/2 port. The OP hasn't stated that they tried it and it didn't work. The question seems to be more along the lines of "should a Y-splitter" work?" To which the best answer (without having a Libretto and Y-splitter in hand) is, "yes, it should". A better answer would be "yes, it does" or "no, it doesn't", which someone who has these two things in hand, would be able to provide.

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR: Try It.

A splitter won't harm the port, worst that can happen is that the mouse won't work.

---

> Through the use of the official dock

Which one? Toshiba offered two different ones, the

- I/O-Adaptor CAB0356A

which in some countries were delivered with the base unit and intended for portable use, while the

- Enhanced Port Replicator PA2719U,

is supposed to support stationary installation (it also features a desk lock). It offers essentially the same ports plus two type 3 PCMCIA and USB.

> I'm able to use a VGA port for video and the 2.5mm audio output.

AFAIR those are not part of either dock. Both leave a notch to connect to them at the base unit.

> According to the manual it has a PS/2 keyboard/mouse port. So using this port directly I can either connect a keyboard or mouse, but not both.

Only the I/O-Adaptor has a single port for both, the Port Replicator has one for each.

> My question is whether it's possible to use a PS/2 splitter cable so that I can connect both a keyboard and mouse at the same time?

With the Port Replicator you need to use either dedicated port.

The I/O-Adaptor does (to my memory) only provide a single PS/2 port, thus only keyboard *or* mouse can be used. Then again, it's risk free to try a splitter. The worst that can happen is that one device (usually mouse) won't work.